# Cambiar estilo componente angular-cli

Tags: javascript, angularjs-2.0

Como puedo cambiar el estilo a un componente, utilizando angular material, estoy haciendo el cambio a la directiva directamente, pero no lo toma...?

`home.component.html`

```
<md-card>
 <app-home></app-home>
</md-card>
```

`home.component.css`

```
md-card {
  max-width: 60px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando *Angular 2* compila los estilos dentro del componente al que está vinculado también la vista, a todos los estilos, se les añade un sufijo relacionado con el componente, y como dentro de tu vista estás usando un componente externo (del paquete material) el compilador lo toma como si no tuviera relación y no le pone los mismos prefijos.

Si estás usando *Angular CLI* lo mejor que puedes hacer es poner el estilo que deseas cambiar de `md-card` en el archivo **styles.css** que se encuentra en la misma carpeta que **main.ts**, y si quieres que solo cambie ese, puedes ponerle una clase dentro de tu vista.

**home.component.html**

```
<md-card class="custom-md-card">
 <app-home></app-home>
</md-card>
```

**styles.css**

```
md-card.custom-md-card {
  max-width: 60px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres que el estilo se refleje en toda la aplicacion usa el archivo style.css, si quieres que solo aplique al componente en el que estas puedes asociar un archivo .css al mismo dentro del decorador (si usas angular-cli ya te crea uno vacio)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'mi-selector',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
```